# Attribute error running OpenCV and imutils

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, computer-vision

I tried to run the following code to do some face recognition application using OpenCV on jupyter Notebook

```
# load the input image and show its dimensions, keeping in mind that
# images are represented as a multi-dimensional NumPy array with
# shape no. rows (height) x no. columns (width) x no. channels (depth)
image = cv2.imread("jp.png")
(h, w, d) = image.shape
print("width={}, height={}, depth={}".format(w, h, d))
# display the image to our screen -- we will need to click the window
# open by OpenCV and press a key on our keyboard to continue execution
cv2.imshow("Image", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

but got the following attribute error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-eaae43cadc51> in <module>
      3 # shape no. rows (height) x no. columns (width) x no. channels (depth)
      4 image = cv2.imread("jp.png")
----> 5 (h, w, d) = image.shape
      6 print("width={}, height={}, depth={}".format(w, h, d))
      7 # display the image to our screen -- we will need to click the window

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

What could have been the problem here?

Comment: It seems the image is of `'NoneType'`. Can you check if the image exists? What is the output if you print `image`?

Comment: image isnt in the location specified.

Comment: Yes, image is in a folder on my desktop. I used desktop/opencv-tutorial.zip/jp.png as the appropriate directory.